# String with variables and values to Objects/Array

Tags: javascript, json

White iterating through JSON data, I've some variables as flat strings with property name and values

row 1

```
"propertyurl: http://link1, imageurl: http://image1.jpg"
```

row 2

```
"propertyurl: http://link2, imageurl: http://image2.jpg"
```

row 3

```
"propertyurl: http://link3, imageurl: http://image3.jpg"
```

I'd like split and return an object as follows (basically JSON format)

```
{ propertyurl: "link1", imageurl: "image2.jpg" }
```

I've tried

```
for(var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(entries[i].content.$t));
}
```

Edit:
added http:// to the links

Comment: @juvian I simplified and tested in developer tools, JSON.parse("{" + "a:1, b:2" + "}"); but it throws an error, SyntaxError: Unexpected token a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string format is *that* predictable, you split the line on the commas and the on the colons:

```
var s = "propertyurl: link3, imageurl: image2.jpg"; // One of the rows you've shown in the OP
var obj = {};
s.split(",").forEach(function (property) {
    var kv = property.split(": ");      
    obj[kv[0].trim()] = kv[1].trim();
});
```

Essentially what you are doing is looping over the string and assigning the values as they appear to `obj`, which you can then use.

Edit:
Added space after the colon

Comment: a bit of problem, my links have http://, so that property.split(":") is splitting the link as well. Same with image links

Answer (score 0):

Your json string is missing quotes and is not valid json. image2.jpg is not "image2.jpg".

You need `JSON.parse('{"propertyurl": "link3", "imageurl": "image2.jpg"}');`

Comment: He's describing a string which needs to be converted to object key/value pairs. He's not claiming that each string in the JSON data is valid JSON.

Comment: Ceres, honestly that's how it is coming from Google Docs Spreadsheet, simply one variable has all columns as a flat string like above, I can't edit the string, anyway we can work with the way string is

Comment: Sorry missed that, @Whymarrh has the right idea then.